# PHP regexp parse HTML

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

My regexp:

```
<([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>[\na-zA-Z0-9]*<\/\1+>
```

my string:

```
<div>
<f>
</f>
</div>
```

the result is:

```
array(2
  0 =>  array(1
  0 =>  <f>
</f>
)
1   =>  array(1
0   =>  f
)
)
```

why it is capturing `<f></f>`, and ignoring the first `<div>` ?

Comment: html CANNOT be parsed with regexes except for vey simple things. You are trying to parse a whole html fragment with regex, which cannot be done, except if you apply regex recursively (meaning inside the xml labels new HTML fragments can also be present, which CANNOT be done with a single regex)

Comment: Because `<` and `>` are not in your second character class.

Comment: @NikosM.: it's false, pcre (the regex engine used by PHP) has a recursion feature.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, true but not enough to parse html (except for simple things)

Comment: @NikosM.: to be clear, it is not easy to write a pattern that matches a whole html document, for example, (long pattern,more or less advanced regex features, need to think to all cases and to define yourself a tolerance for bad formatted things and default behaviors (like `DOMDocument` has)) but it is possible.

Comment: @NikosM.: a typical use case is when `DOMDocument` (that fixes automatically unclosed tags) does not fix your document the way you want for a tag in particular.

Comment: @NikosM. One **can** parse a html document with regex.

Comment: @Jan, one can indeed parse many things with regexes, it depends of course on what is meant by *parsing*, some things cannot be parsed by regexes (think of nested html fragments where tag attributes are in random order in each case, to give a simple yet usual example)

Comment: @NikosM. Right you are about the parsing terminology.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **USE A PARSER INSTEAD** (sorry for my *shouting*). While it is sometimes faster to use a regular expression to obtain an ID or URL string, html tags need a rather error-prone way of understanding via regex. Consider the following code, isn't that much more beautiful than druidic characters with special meanings?

```
<?php
$str = "
<container>
    <div class='someclass' data='somedata'>
        <f>some content here</f>
    </div>
</container>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

echo $xml->div->f; // some content here
$attributes = $xml->div->attributes();
print_r($attributes); // class and data as keys
?>
```

Comment: i would agree although user most probably wants a regex-based approach (even if suboptimal)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's because your second character class statement tries to find 0 or more of the characters before the ending tag comes, and that doesn't match with the `<div>...</div>` block.