# Intellij regular expression search in XML atributes

Tags: java, regex, xml, intellij-idea, structural-search

I'm using Intellij and I want to search for XML attributes.

For example this XML line:

```
<img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael' />
```

I want to search my project for any other instances of this line:

```
<img src="BLABLALBA" alt='BLABLALBA' />
```

I tried using this regular expression : `src="\W"` but no results was found.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In short: better use a parser instead. Similar question answered yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252497/php-regexp-parse-html/34253108#34253108

Comment: [Parsing XML with regex is generally considered a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3991344).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Structural Search & Replace (`Edit | Find | Search Structurally...`). Use the following pattern:

```
<img src="$A$" alt="$B$" />
```

And set the file type to XML or HTML depending on what type of files you are searching.